# Sources from referenced projects are not deployed to Tomcat in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have setup a dynamic web project in eclipse with JSF in which I trust on code from another project (framework). Therefore, I added the framework project to the build path of the website project.

So far so good, Eclipse recognises every class and the project builds without errors.

Problem is though that when I do "run on server" to test it on tomcat 6.0.24, the application fails. I get ClassNotFoundException on every class from the framework project.

Is this a bug or is some specific configuration necessary for this?

Answer (score 8):

I was googling and ended up here for a similar problem. I wanted to make a note for others about the current situation on Eclipse Indigo, as the terminology has changed a bit by the looks of things.

On your project properties, do a filter/search for "deployment assembly".

It is then straightforward to add a project dependency. Job Done.

Thanks to Alexander's edited answer which led me to this.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check Warnings in `Problems` view?

Do you see `Classpath entry /your/framework.jar will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result` warning?

If you do.

1. Right-Click the warning and choose `Quick Fix`.
2. Choose "Mark the associated entry as publish/export dependency." from `Select a Fix` box.
3. Click `Finish`.

**EDIT**
Now, I think I understand where disconnect is.  I think now I remember the joy of figuring this out for the first time.

In your website project ( I will speculate here , but I guess you've created it as a `Dynamic Web Project` ):

1. Open project properties
2. Select `Java EE Module Dependencies` panel
3. Check your framework project in `JAR/Module` column.  Beware, that for reasons not known to me, the list is not sorted ( and is not sortable ) in any particular order, so you may need to search for your project reference there.

The results of this operation will be written to `/website-project/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component` file.  Put this file into your source control.

Comment: No nothing, I only see some code related warnings, nothing I didn't expect (deprecation and such things).

Comment: @Steven. Did you mark framework jar files as exported in Build Path `Order and Export` tab?

Comment: Actually I think the problem is that there is no framework.jar, instead only the framework sources in the framework project which I need to use and deploy when running my website project.

I expect I need to modify the org.eclipse.wst.common.component file, but I cannot work out how I add an entry that refers to a different project.

Comment: I haven't found an ideal solution yet, but I have added an ant builder task to my framework project to automatically create a jar of my framework, and then use that jar from the website project.

Comment: @Steven. I've updated my answer, please check if that helps you.